# How to smoothly finish infinity animation

Tags: swift, core-animation

I have infinity `CABasicAnimation` which actually simulate pulsating by increasing and decreasing scale:

```
scaleAnimation.fromValue = 0.5
scaleAnimation.toValue = 1.0
scaleAnimation.duration = 0.8

scaleAnimation.autoreverses = true
scaleAnimation.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
scaleAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
```

I want to smoothly stop this animation in `toValue`. In other words, I want to allow current animation cycle finish, but stop repeating. Is there a nice and clean way to do this? I had a few ideas about freezing current animation, removing it and creating a new one with time offset, but maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard way to do this cleanly — though it's actually quite tricky if you don't know about it:

1. The first thing you do is set the layer's scale to the scale of its `presentationLayer`.
2. Then call `removeAllAnimations` on the layer.
3. Now do a fast animation where you set the layer's scale to 1.

Here's a possible implementation (for extra credit, I suppose we could adjust the duration of the fast animation to match what the current scale is, but I didn't bother to do that here):

```
@IBAction func doStop(_ sender: Any) {
    let lay = v.layer
    lay.transform = lay.presentation()!.transform
    lay.removeAllAnimations()
    CATransaction.flush()
    lay.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    let scaleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
    scaleAnimation.duration = 0.4
    scaleAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeOut)
    lay.add(scaleAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Simplified my example code quite considerably. Simpler and looks a lot better too.